# Clojure: reduce vs. apply

Tags: clojure

I understand the conceptual difference between `reduce` and `apply`:

```
(reduce + (list 1 2 3 4 5))
; translates to: (+ (+ (+ (+ 1 2) 3) 4) 5)

(apply + (list 1 2 3 4 5))
; translates to: (+ 1 2 3 4 5)
```

However, which one is more idiomatic clojure?  Does it make much difference one way or the other?  From my (limited) performance testing, it seems `reduce` is a bit faster.

Comment: it basically doesn't matter unless you have a reason to care about performance. I like + better because it shows how the + function is not retarded and can accept any number of arguments like you would expect.

Comment: Also, in terms of portability consider [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5350027/213136) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331746/practical-use-of-fold-reduce-in-functional-languages?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 132, accepted):

`reduce` and `apply` are of course only equivalent (in terms of the ultimate result returned) for associative functions which need to see all their arguments in the variable-arity case. When they are result-wise equivalent, I'd say that `apply` is always perfectly idiomatic, while `reduce` is equivalent -- and might shave off a fraction of a blink of an eye -- in a lot of the common cases. What follows is my rationale for believing this.

`+` is itself implemented in terms of `reduce` for the variable-arity case (more than 2 arguments). Indeed, this seems like an immensely sensible "default" way to go for any variable-arity, associative function: `reduce` has the potential to perform some optimisations to speed things up -- perhaps through something like `internal-reduce`, a 1.2 novelty recently disabled in master, but hopefully to be reintroduced in the future -- which it would be silly to replicate in every function which might benefit from them in the vararg case. In such common cases, `apply` will just add a little overhead. (Note it's nothing to be really worried about.)

On the other hand, a complex function might take advantage of some optimisation opportunities which aren't general enough to be built into `reduce`; then `apply` would let you take advantage of those while `reduce` might actually slow you down. A good example of the latter scenario occuring in practice is provided by `str`: it uses a `StringBuilder` internally and will benefit significantly from the use of `apply` rather than `reduce`.

So, I'd say use `apply` when in doubt; and if you happen to know that it's not buying you anything over `reduce` (and that this is unlikely to change very soon), feel free to use `reduce` to shave off that diminutive unnecessary overhead if you feel like it.

Comment: Great answer.  On a side note, why not include a built-in `sum` function like in haskell?  Seems like a pretty common operation.

Comment: Thanks, happy to hear that! Re: `sum`, I'd say that Clojure has this function, it's called `+` and you can use it with `apply`. :-) Seriously speaking, I think in Lisp, in general, if a variadic function is provided, it's not usually accompanied by a wrapper operating on collections -- that's what you use `apply` for (or `reduce`, if you know that makes more sense).

Comment: Funny, my advice is the opposite: `reduce` when in doubt, `apply` when you know for sure there's an optimization. `reduce`'s contract is more precise and thus more prone to general optimization. `apply` is more vague and thus can only be optimized on a case-by-case basis. `str` and `concat` are the two prevalent exceptons.

Comment: @cgrand A rephrasing of my rationale might be roughly that for functions where `reduce` and `apply` are equivalent in terms of results, I'd expect the author of the function in question to know how best to optimize their variadic overload and just implement it in terms of `reduce` if that's indeed what makes the most sense (the option to do so is certainly always available and makes for an eminently sensible default). I do see where you're coming from, though, `reduce` is definitely central to Clojure's performance story (and increasingly so), very highly optimized and very clearly specified.

Comment: @dbyrne: Clojure doesn't supply a `sum` function in order to give language lawyers something (else) to argue about.

Answer (score 57):

For newbies looking at this answer,
be careful, they are not the same:

```
(apply hash-map [:a 5 :b 6])
;= {:a 5, :b 6}
(reduce hash-map [:a 5 :b 6])
;= {{{:a 5} :b} 6}
```

Answer (score 24):

It doesn't make a difference in this case, because + is a special case that can apply to any number of arguments. Reduce is a way to apply a function that expects a fixed number of arguments (2) to an arbitrarily long list of arguments.

Answer (score 22):

Opinions vary- In the greater Lisp world, `reduce` is definitely considered more idiomatic. First, there is the variadic issues already discussed. Also, some Common Lisp compilers will actually fail when `apply` is applied against very long lists because of how they handle argument lists.

Amongst Clojurists in my circle, though, using `apply` in this case seems more common. I find it easier to grok and prefer it also.

Answer (score 11):

I normally find myself preferring reduce when acting on any kind of collection - it performs well, and is a pretty useful function in general.

The main reason I would use apply is if the parameters mean different things in different positions, or if you have a couple of initial parameters but want to get the rest from a collection, e.g.

```
(apply + 1 2 other-number-list)
```

Answer (score 11):

In this specific case I prefer `reduce` because it's more **readable**: when I read

```
(reduce + some-numbers)
```

I know immediately that you're turning a sequence into a value.

With `apply` I have to consider which function is being applied: "ah, it's the `+` function, so I'm getting... a single number". Slightly less straightforward.

Answer (score 10):

When using a simple function like +, it really doesn't matter which one you use.

In general, the idea is that `reduce` is an accumulating operation.  You present the current accumulation value and one new value to your accumulating function The result of the function is the cumulative value for the next iteration.  So, your iterations look like:

```
cum-val[i+1] = F( cum-val[i], input-val[i] )    ; please forgive the java-like syntax!
```

For apply, the idea is that you are attempting to call a function expecting a number of scalar arguments, but they are currently in a collection and need to be pulled out.  So, instead of saying:

```
vals = [ val1 val2 val3 ]
(some-fn (vals 0) (vals 1) (vals 2))
```

we can say:

```
(apply some-fn vals)
```

and it is converted to be equivalent to:

```
(some-fn val1 val2 val3)
```

So, using "apply" is like "removing the parentheses" around the sequence.

Answer (score 5):

The beauty of apply is given function (+ in this case) can be applied to argument list formed by pre-pending intervening arguments with an ending collection. Reduce is an abstraction to process collection items applying the function for each and doesn't work with variable args case.

```
(apply + 1 2 3 [3 4])
=> 13
(reduce + 1 2 3 [3 4])
ArityException Wrong number of args (5) passed to: core/reduce  clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity (AFn.java:429)
```

Answer (score 4):

Bit late on the topic but I did a simple experiment after reading this example. Here is result from my repl, I just can't deduce anything from the response, but seems there is some sort of caching kick in between reduce and apply.

```
user=> (time (reduce + (range 1e3)))
"Elapsed time: 5.543 msecs"
499500
user=> (time (apply + (range 1e3))) 
"Elapsed time: 5.263 msecs"
499500
user=> (time (apply + (range 1e4)))
"Elapsed time: 19.721 msecs"
49995000
user=> (time (reduce + (range 1e4)))
"Elapsed time: 1.409 msecs"
49995000
user=> (time (reduce + (range 1e5)))
"Elapsed time: 17.524 msecs"
4999950000
user=> (time (apply + (range 1e5)))
"Elapsed time: 11.548 msecs"
4999950000
```

Looking at source code of clojure reduce its pretty clean recursion with internal-reduce, didn't found anything on implementation of apply though. Clojure implementation of + for apply internally invoke reduce, which is cached by repl, which seem to explain the 4th call. Can someone clarify whats really happening here?

Comment: I know I will prefer reduce whenever I can :)

Comment: You shouldn't put the `range` call inside the `time` form. Put it outside to remove the interference of sequence construction. In my case, `reduce` consistently outperforms `apply`.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but...

In this case, there is not a big difference.  But in general they are not equivalent. Further more reduce can be more performant. Why?

reduce checks if a collection or type implements [IReduced](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.10.1/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L6810) interface. That means a type knows how provide its values to the reducing function in the most performant why.
reduce can be stopped prematurely by returning a Reduced value.

Apply on the other hand, is invoked by [applyToHelper](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/38bafca9e76cd6625d8dce5fb6d16b87845c8b9d/src/jvm/clojure/lang/AFn.java#L147). Which dispatches to the right arity by counting the args, unpacking the values from the collection.

Is it a big performance impact? Probably not.
My opinion is as others already pointed out. Use reduce if you want to semantically "reduce" a collection to a single value. Otherwise use apply.