# In clojure, what is an efficient way to calculate average of integer vectors

Tags: matlab, clojure

I have:

```
(def data [[1 3 4 7 9] [7 6 3 2 7] [1 9 8 6 2]])
```

I want to average these (element-wise to get):

```
[3 6 5 5 6]
```

Like you would in MATLAB:

```
mean([1 3 4 7 9; 7 6 3 2 7; 1 9 8 6 2])
```

With Incanter I can do:

```
(map #(/ % (count m)) (apply plus data))
```

If data is rather large (and I have lots of them) is there a better way to do this?
Does it help to calculate the `(count m)` beforehand?
Does it help to `defn` the `#(/ % (count m))` beforehand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without knowing how to use any of incanter, here's how you could do this "from scratch".

```
(let [data [[1 3 4 7 9] [7 6 3 2 7] [1 9 8 6 2]]
      num (count data)]
  (apply map (fn [& items]
               (/ (apply + items) num))
         data))

;=> (3 6 5 5 6)
```

Comment: Thanks @amalloy it works, but I don't understand how `(apply map (fn ...` would work, shouldn't it be `(apply (map (fn ...` ?

Comment: @Ali No, you're applying the `map` function to a sequence of arguments: an anonymous function we construct, and then each element of the `data` sequence. `map` is willing to accept "extra" arguments, by passing them along to the function. For example, `(map + [1 2] [10 20])` ~= `[(+ 1 10) (+ 2 20)]`.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a pretty clean and simple way to do it:

```
(def data [[1 3 4 7 9] [7 6 3 2 7] [1 9 8 6 2]])

(defn average [coll] 
  (/ (reduce + coll) (count coll)))

(defn transpose [coll]
   (apply map vector coll))

(map average (transpose data))
=> (3 6 5 5 6)
```

Comment: Asked myself if (apply + coll) would be more efficient then (reduce + coll). Already answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153396/clojure-reduce-vs-apply

Comment: Reduce is very slightly faster (about 5-10% in informal tests I've just done). But it's down to personal preference really - I tend to think in reduction operations more readily than I do in parameter juggling.

Answer (score 8):

As of 2013, my recommendation would be to just use [core.matrix.stats](https://github.com/clojure-numerics/core.matrix.stats) to import all of this functionality:

```
(mean [[1 3 4 7 9] [7 6 3 2 7] [1 9 8 6 2]])
=> [3.0 6.0 5.0 5.0 6.0]
```

core.matrix.stats builds on the core.matrix API, so it will also work on other more optimised implementations of vectors and matrices - this is likely to be a better option if you are doing a lot of heavy matrix processing.