# Add items in a list/sequence in Clojure

Tags: clojure

There has to be a simple way to do this, and I am obviously missing it :|

How do you add the items in a list\sequence (not clear on the difference) in clojure?

I've tried the following:

```
Clojure> (add [1 2 3])
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: add in this context
Clojure> (+ [1 2 3])
java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast clojure.lang.PersistentVector to java.lang.Number
Clojure> (apply merge-with + [1 2 3])
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know how to create ISeq from: java.lang.Long
Clojure> (add-items [1 2 3])
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: add-items in this context
```

Comment: you mean like  `(apply + [1 2 3])`  ?

Comment: Yes, @NathanHughes - that is what I was looking for. I don't know why I couldn't figure something so simple out, but yes - that was it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
(+ 1 2 3)
```

...will do it. @Nathan Hughes's solution:

```
(apply + [1 2 3])
```

...works if you have a reference to the sequence rather than defining it inline, e.g.:

```
(def s [1 2 3])
; (+ s) CastClassException
(apply + s) ; 6
```

As @4e6 notes, `reduce` also works:

```
(reduce + s) ; 6
```

Which is better? [Opinions vary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153396/clojure-reduce-vs-apply).

Comment: I believe `(reduce + [1 2 3])` is more idiomatic.

Comment: @4e6: [You may be right.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153396/clojure-reduce-vs-apply)

Comment: (reduce + [1 2 3]) doesn't really make sense to me, since + already uses reduce: https://github.com/richhickey/clojure/blob/a1eff35124b923ef8539a35e7a292813ba54a0e0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L797

Comment: @4e6 as far as I can tell, a lot of clojurians seem to prefer (apply + [1 2 3]), although other lisps prefer reduce. I guess "apply" conveys the intent of the function better.

Comment: (reduce + [1 2 3]) is probably best once the new Reducers functionality is released - reduce will get a lot more optimisations: http://clojure.com/blog/2012/05/08/reducers-a-library-and-model-for-collection-processing.html