# In clojure, map and stringify: make it simpler

Tags: clojure, lisp

### map and stringify

I have this piece of `clojure` code:

```
(def up (memfn toUpperCase))   
(str "\n" (apply str (interpose "\n" (map up '("one" "two")))) "\n"); "\nONE\nTWO\n"
```

The code does exactly what it is supposed to do: take a list of string, uppercase each one and envelop each one with a `\n` (inc before and after).

But there must be a way to write this in a more **elegant** way. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with:

```
 (defn interpose-envelop-and-stringify [coll sep]
   (str sep
        (join sep coll)
        sep))
 (interpose-envelop-and-stringify (map up ["one" "two"]) "\n")
```

I am using `join` from [clojure.string](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.string-api.html#clojure.string/join).

Answer (score 4):

you could combine the map and interpose:

```
(apply str "\n" (map #(str (up %) "\n") '("one" "two")))
```

also, not necessarily more elegant, bit in the spirit of timtowdi:

```
(clojure.pprint/cl-format false "~%~{~:@(~A~)~%~}" '("one" "two"))
```

see [practical common lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/a-few-format-recipes.html) for a tutorial on cl format strings.

Comment: Nice. But I guess that there should be an even more elegant way to interpose with header and footer. What do you think?

Comment: the problem is you're not interposing, you're "outerposing", so to speak.

Comment: Yes!  *“In the elder days there would have been at least a few followups showing how to do this in the proper "FORMAT string indistinguishable from line noise" way.”* —[Tim Bradshaw, comp.lang.lisp](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.lisp/msg/54beeed56ec2c5de)

Answer (score 4):

I actually quite like the `with-out-str` approach to this sort of thing:

```
(with-out-str
  (println)
  (doseq [s ["one" "two"]]
    (println (.toUpperCase ^String s))))
```

It seems to be about 2-3x slower than your original approach and Martin's "combined map and interpose" variant with type hints added (and ~30x faster than `cl-format`, which however clearly wins on the coolness factor :-)). (See end of this answer for a note on hinting & reflection.)

Another version just to keep up the timtowtdi spirit: for the ultimate in speed (up to ~2x speedup over your original version), should you have reason to care about that, you could use

```
(loop [sb (doto (StringBuilder.)
            (.append \newline))
       strs ["one" "two"]]
  (if-let [s (first strs)]
    (do (.append sb (.toUpperCase ^String s))
        (.append sb \newline)
        (recur sb (next strs)))
    (.toString sb)))))
```

Somewhat tangentially to the main question, I timed all approaches after getting rid of all reflection warnings; in particular, I used

```
(def up #(.toUpperCase ^String %))
```

(Incidentally, `#(.foo %)` seems to be used *much* more often than `memfn` even when no type hints are specified.)

Comment: The problem with `#(.foo %)` is that you have to worry manually with the number of args while this is not the case with `memfn`.

Comment: That's not true, you need to say something like `(memfn foo a b c)` (using arbitrary symbols in place of `a b c`, as long as they are pairwise different) to create a wrapper for a method taking three arguments. See `(source memfn)` for details.

Answer (score 0):

You do the right thing.
One advise - use function arg or let form to define separator, in that case when you need change separator you change it only in one place (not 3 as in your case)

```
(defn stringify [sq sep]
  (reduce str sep (map #(str (.toUpperCase %) sep) sq)))

(stringify ["one" "two"] "\n") => "\nONE\nTWO\n"
```

Comment: One note: `str` works best with `apply` (rather than `reduce`) -- it uses a `StringBuilder` internally when called with multiple arguments, so it's better to let it handle its own looping. (It's an instance of a more general pattern which I discussed in [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3153643/232707) some time ago.)

Comment: Thanks! I perform some tests apply str vs reduce str, and for 100k strings apply much better. In other way reduce + slightly better than apply +. (I read your comment to related question, makes sense)

Answer (score 0):

The thrush operation can make things reasonably clean, but there's still an enclosing apply that's needed to join the list into one big string.

```
(defn stringify [s] (apply str "\n" (map #(-> % .toUpperCase (str "\n")) s)))

(stringify '("one" "two")) ; yields "\nONE\nTWO\n"
```