# Function in order to show a TicTacToe board : can it be simplified and more readable?

Tags: clojure

As I am learning clojure, I am trying to build a simple tic tac toe game, without ia. I started with a method in order to show a board, but it seems very ugly to me : i am using internal functions, in order to make them local to the show-board method, so that it can't be instantiated outside. Perhaps the reason of the bad looking.

Here is the function (which works as I want) :

```
(defn show-board [board]
    "Prints the board on the screen.
     Board must be a list of three lists of three elements with
     :cross for a cross and :circle for a circle, other value for nothing"
    (let [convert-elem (fn [elem] 
                            (cond
                                    (= elem :cross) "X"
                                    (= elem :circle) "O"
                                    :other "_"))
          convert-line (fn [elems-line]
                            (reduce str (map convert-elem elems-line)))]
         (doseq [line board]
            (println (convert-line line)))))
```

Here is a use case :

```
(show-board (list (list :cross :circle :none) (list :none :circle :none) (list :cross :none :none)))
```

Sorry for the ugly code, this is because I come from Java, and I am starting in Clojure. (I think I will really get benefits from learning Clojure, and make games with it, so I can't just leave it).

Another reason why I want to simplify it is for code maintenance and readability.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about simply letting the underlying writer to buffer the output rather than creating intermediate strings (even if you create them through a `StringBuilder`)?

```
=> (defn show-board [board]
     (doseq [line board]
       (doseq [item line]
         (print ({:cross \X :circle \O} item \_)))
       (newline)))
```

And if you want to get a string rather than print them out, just use `with-out-str`.

Answer (score 2):

Using internal functions is perfectly fine, though in this case using `letfn` would perhaps look better. Additionally, `convert-elem` can be simplified with `case` and `convert-line` should use `apply` rather than `reduce` for reasons I explained in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153396/clojure-reduce-vs-apply/3153643#3153643) to the [Clojure: reduce vs. apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153396/clojure-reduce-vs-apply) SO question (in short, with `apply` a single `StringBuilder` is used and the resulting process is linear; with `reduce`, each step involves allocating a new `StringBuilder` and the process is quadratic; this doesn't make much difference is a small case like this, but it is nonetheless better style to use the correct approach).

Here's the modified function:

```
(defn show-board [board]
  "Prints the board on the screen.
   Board must be a list of three lists of three elements with
   :cross for a cross and :circle for a circle, other value for
   nothing."
  (letfn [(convert-elem [elem] 
            (case elem
              :cross "X"
              :circle "O"
              "_"))
          (convert-line [elems-line]
            (apply str (map convert-elem elems-line)))]
    (doseq [line board]
      (println (convert-line line)))))
```

As a side note, this function actually takes an arbitrary seqable of seqables, not necessarily a list of lists. A more usual concrete type choice in Clojure would be to use vectors:

```
user> (show-board [[:cross :circle :none]
                   [:none :circle :none]
                   [:cross :none :none]])
XO_
_O_
X__
nil
```

Comment: `convert-element` function can be replaced with a map `{:cross \X :circle \O :none \_}`. IMHO it is more concise.

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov Right, as long as the spec (as expressed in the docstring) is changed to require `:none` as the "empty" value. Or we could use `{:cross \X :circle \O}` and look up the result with `(get convert-elem elem \_)`.

Comment: Yes. I can add that but you can do it without `get`: `(convert-elem elem \_)`.

Comment: Wow :) Thank you very much. Didn't know letfn : will use it know when appropriate. Did not know for the complexity of reduce when dealing with strings. Thank also for the comments for the "\" reader.

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov Indeed. Thanks for the comments! @LaurentBERNABE To add one more remark to the answer, while I think doing everything in one function is fine in this case (as it's really simple), if this logic were to become more involved it would probably make sense to pull things apart -- put the internal functions at top level (possibly marking them private), make a separate function construct a representation of the board useful for printing (a string or seq of strings), then make `show-board` call that function. That way it would all stay clear and testable despite the extra complexity.

Comment: I had a doubt for whether to describe the board as list or as a vector, but you're right, vectors are better (the first value can't be interpreted as a function).

Comment: @MichałMarczyk Ok, I will search for the private option and use it in my code. Thanks again.

Comment: Finally, here is my modifications, with all your advices : http://pastebin.com/vNNMV80R

Answer (score 2):

```
(defn show-board
  [board]
  (let [convert (fn [el] (get {:cross \X :circle \O} el \_))]
    (doseq [line board]
      (doseq [el line]
        (print (convert el)))
      (println))))
```

Comment: Apart from its beauty, this also reminds me the nested for of Java-like languages (it is simpler than our previous attempt).