# How to sum all values in a hashmap?

Tags: clojure, hashmap, sum, reduce

In Clojure, I have a map like this:

```
(def data {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3})
```

I want to sum all the elements and get `6` as a result. I know I should probably use `reduce`, but I'm at a loss at how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two easy ways you can do this.

With `reduce`

```
(reduce + (vals data))
```

Or with `apply`

```
(apply + (vals data))
```

[They are equivalent for associative functions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153396/clojure-reduce-vs-apply)

I'd suggest that `apply` is more idiomatic, because [+ is already implemented via reduce](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.7.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L949).

That is, if we calculate `(+ 1 2 3)`, the result is 6. So it's natural to ask why `(+ (vals data))` isn't sufficient.

The result of `(vals data)` is the list `(1 2 3)`. `+` sees this as a single argument and just returns that value... oops.

```
(+ (vals data))
=> (1 2 3)
```

`apply` [works by essentially unpacking the list](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.7.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L625).

Answer (score 5):

You are correct, you should reduce here.  `vals` will get you the values you want to add up, then just `reduce` them over the addition function.

```
user=> (def data {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3})
#'user/data
user=> (vals data)
(3 2 1)
user=> (reduce + (vals data)) 
6
```