# How to use reduce and into properly

Tags: clojure

I'm learning Clojure and actually I'm doing some exercises to practice but I'm stuck in a problem:

I need to make a `sum-consecutives` function which sums consecutive elements in a array, resulting in a new one, as example:

```
[1,4,4,4,0,4,3,3,1]  ; should return [1,12,0,4,6,1]
```

I made this function which should work just fine:

```
(defn sum-consecutives [a]
  (reduce #(into %1 (apply + %2)) [] (partition-by identity a)))
```

But it throws an error:

> IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from:
>   java.lang.Long  clojure.lang.RT.seqFrom (RT.java:542)

Can anyone help me see what is wrong with my func? I've already search this error in web but I find no helpful solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll likely want to use [`conj`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/conj) instead of `into`, as `into` is expecting its second argument to be a [`seq`](https://clojure.org/reference/sequences):

```
(defn sum-consecutives [a]
  (reduce 
    #(conj %1 (apply + %2))
    [] 
    (partition-by identity a)))

(sum-consecutives [1,4,4,4,0,4,3,3,1]) ;; [1 12 0 4 6 1]
```

Alternatively, if you *really* wanted to use `into`, you could wrap your call to `apply +` in a vector literal like so:

```
(defn sum-consecutives [a]
  (reduce 
    #(into %1 [(apply + %2)])
    [] 
    (partition-by identity a)))
```

Comment: Your conj resolution worked fine showing exactly what I was missing. I'm going study deeper about these functions. thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is sound in starting with `partition-by`.  But let's
walk through the steps to sum each subsequence that it produces.

```
(let [xs [1 4 4 4 0 4 3 3 1]]
  (partition-by identity xs))  ;=> ((1) (4 4 4) (0) (4) (3 3) (1))
```

To get a sum, you can use `reduce` (though a simple `apply`
instead [would also work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3153643/326516)
here); e.g.:

```
(reduce + [4 4 4])  ;=> 12
```

Now put it all together to `reduce` each subsequence from above with `map`:

```
(let [xs [1 4 4 4 0 4 3 3 1]]
  (map #(reduce + %) (partition-by identity xs)))  ;=> (1 12 0 4 6 1)
```

#### A few notes...

I'm using `xs` to represent your vector (as suggested by the
[Clojure Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/clojure-style-guide#naming)).

The `let` is sometimes a convenient form for experimenting with some
data building up to eventual functions.

Commas are not needed and are usually distracting, except occasionally
with hash-maps.

So your final function based on all this could look something like:

```
(defn sum-consecutives [coll]
  (map #(reduce + %) (partition-by identity coll)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your  resolution and tips. I'll work over them